# How to initialize an array of pointers to a struct in C++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, initialization, private-members

UPDATE :
Answer at the bottom.

Hi Guys,

How to initialize an 'array of pointers to a struct' ? The catch is, the array is a member variable and the size passed to the declaration of the array in the constructor is variable entity.

```
    typedef struct Node {
        string key;
        int value;
        struct Node * left;
        struct Node * right;
    }doubly;

    class myHashStrKey{

    private:
        size_t hashsize;
        doubly * table[];

    public:
        myHashStrKey(){
            hashsize = ((size_t)-1);
            doubly * table[hashsize];
            memset(table,NULL,hashsize);// This is giving segmentation fault
        }

    };

//Called constructor;    myHashStrKey sss = myHashStrKey();
```

Here I want the table to be a array of pointers to the Doubly nodes and I want all the pointers to be initialized to NULL . Whats wrong with this code here ? What other better way are there to perform the above ? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE :

After the discussion, considering the size is big let down I have modified the code . But how to fill vector table with certain number of NULL values ?I tried the below code but it is not working .

```
<pre><code>
for(int i =0;i < hashsize;i++){
            table.push_back((doubly *)NULL);
        }

table.insert(table.begin(),hashsize,NULL);
//Both give invalid static_cast from type `int' to type `doubly*'
</code></pre>
```

ANSWER UPDATE :

```
    myHashStrKey::table(myHashStrKey::hashsize, static_cast(0));
    myHashStrKey::table(myHashStrKey::hashsize);
    //Above 2 does not work

    for(int i =0;i != myHashStrKey::hashsize;i++){ //lesser than symbol spoils the display
        myHashStrKey::table.push_back((doubly *)NULL);
    }
    //Above works 
    myHashStrKey::table.insert(myHashStrKey::table.begin(),hashsize,((doubly *)NULL));
    //This too works
```

Comment: Is this your actual code?  `hashsize = ((size_t)-1);` How do you even get this to compile?

Comment: @Oli: that is casting. and that will compile!

Comment: It does compile and gives the correct value.

Comment: it gives the correct value if 0xFFFFFFFF is defined to be correct. I'd quite like to know why the next line compiles?

Comment: @bsoundra: As @Nawaz pointed out in a now-deleted post, this will create an array that's 18446744073709551615 elements long!  (On a 64-bit machine, at least.)

Comment: @Oli: what's weird is that the compiler allows to create a huge array when an attempt to write even a part of it results in segfault.

Comment: What surprising behavior!  But I guess it's obvious now what's going on thanks to what @Nawaz and @Oli Charlesworth pointed out.  In the constructor, `hashsize` is set to the largest possible value of `size_t`.  Then a local variable `table` is declared with an extremely large size.  (This itself isn't a problem because it's a stack allocation, and no more local variable are declared.)  Finally, `memset` is called on the local with an absurdly large size argument.  This quickly segfaults after zeroing out the stack (if the stack grows down)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable-length arrays are not supported by the C++ standard.  Instead, simply use a `std::vector`:

```
private:
    std::vector<doubly *> table;

...

myHashStrKey()
    : table(num_elements, NULL)  // Initialises vector
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am trying to implement a Hashmap here. I initially tried with tables but it does not support [] assignment. Thats why I am using array. What structure, which would support variable-length array and [] assignment, is available for this purpose ?

Comment: @Oli : You mean std::vector allows [] assignment ? I thought it allows only []access . `vector<int> sss;
    sss[5] = 45;

    cout <<sss[5];` Gives segmentation fault

Comment: @bsoundra: `vector<int> sss;` creates an empty vector (size==0), you need to allocate at least 6 elements for the next line to work. Trying to grab all the memory you can get upfront so that you'll not have to deal with allocations is not the right way to go...

Comment: "Variable-length arrays are not supported by the C++ standard." but some compilers accept them anyway.  (Obviously such compiler are not strictly compliant.)

Comment: `myHashStrKey::hashsize = size/3 +1;`
`myHashStrKey::table(myHashStrKey::hashsize,NULL);`

is giving " error: no match for call to `(std::vector<doubly*, std::allocator<doubly*> >) (int&, NULL)'"

Comment: you're mixing up declaration and intialization. You should really start by some C++ basics. Knowing C is almost useless to learn C++ (can even give you bad habits). This should do the trick as oli said : public: myHashStrKey(int size): hashsize(size/3+1), table(hashsize, NULL) {}

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
        doubly * table[hashsize];
```

creates a **local variable** `table` which over-shades the member of the same name.

Also note that the line

```
        memset(table,NULL,hashsize);// This is giving segmentation fault
```

is not correct as it sets `hashsize` **bytes**, whereas your `table` is an array of `hashsize` **pointers**, each of which is more than one byte (usually 4 on 32-bit machine), i.e. `sizeof(table) >= hashsize * sizeof(doubly*)`

The segfault however is probably a result of trying to write a huge chunk of memory (at least 4G), as @Nawaz pointed out).

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you should really use std::vector.

You should probably look more carefully what the STL has to offer. Otherwise you will miss a lot of C++ nice features and would be doing C with classes. Try to get also familiar with RAII to know more about C++ memory management possibilities (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). Things like memset aren't really much used in modern C++.

Comment: I have now moved to std::vector . But initialization to NULL for certain number of elements is not working . All the above mentioned methods are chucking out errors. Now I starting to doubt if it is possible to fill vector with NULL values!!!

Comment: Seriously ? table(num_elements, NULL) doesn't work ? But anyways, why would you keep a vector full of empty pointers ?